# How do I add my own location in gmap script in mvc

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Code is working fine but i want to add my own location .
for example in below script

map.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(37.4419, -122.1419), 13);

is giving me map for that perticular location if I want Pune,India map
then where I need to put this location or how can I get the lat lng for this location?

how can i do it please help me i'm newbie in mvc.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/jsapi?key=mykey"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        var allMarks = [];
        google.load("maps", "2");

        //This function will help us to add the mark at
        //location where user has double clicked. Then
        //we will add all the marks in our array so that
        //we can send it back to the controller
        function initialize() {
            var map = new google.maps.Map2(document.getElementById("map"));
            map.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(37.4419, -122.1419), 13);
            marker = new google.maps.marker
            map.setUIToDefault();
            GEvent.addListener(map, "dblclick", function(overlay, latlng) {
                if (latlng) {
                    var mark = new GMarker(latlng);
                    allMarks.push(latlng);
                    map.addOverlay(mark);
                }
            });

        }
        google.setOnLoadCallback(initialize);


        //This function will be called for saving the mark
        //for that it will send the data back to the controller
        function saveMap() {

            //gmap object with all values of the map mark
            var gmap = {
                Locations: allMarks,
                Description: Description.value
            }

            //Ajax call for saving the data at the server. It will send the gmap
            //object tot the server
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/Home/Create",
                data: gmap
            });
        }
    </script>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "add my own location?" Add a marker? Center the map? We'll need more info on what you're trying to accomplish in order to help.

Comment: I mean to say that in above script the  map.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(37.4419, -122.1419), 13);
is already given if I want to show the map for Pune,India location then where I need to add this location in the script.?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that you just need to do this once, and not geocode arbitrary locations on the fly, then all you have to do is replace the coordinates in

```
map.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(37.4419, -122.1419), 13);
```

with your own coordinates and zoom level. You can easily find the lat/lon for a location manually in a variety of ways - I like [getlatlon.com](http://www.getlatlon.com).

Was that really your question? If you need to take an arbitrary address, e.g. based on user input, and center the map there, you might want to look at Google's [geocoding API](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/geocoding.html).